# Index match max/min scores (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, indexing, max, min

I am working through a coding assignment and am close to completion save for my final print statement which needs to match names w/ scores for max and min.

I have been able to get appropriate values in two sentences using two if statements, but I am a bit stumped on how to get my indexing correct to align names to scores w/ max and min.

I am not able to use classes or additional / different methods other than arrays and indexing.

```
    //Create method StudentMax
private static int StudentMax(int[] Scores) {
    int ScoreMax = Scores[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < Scores.length; i++){
        if (Scores[i] > ScoreMax){
            ScoreMax = Scores[i];
        }
    }
    return ScoreMax;
}

//Create method StudentMin
private static int StudentMin(int[] Scores) {
    int ScoreMin = Scores[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < Scores.length; i++){
        if (Scores[i] < ScoreMin) {
            ScoreMin = Scores[i];
        }
    }
    return ScoreMin;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Call Scanner
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    //User Welcome
    System.out.println("Welcome to the student score sorter.");
    System.out.println("\nThis program will accept a number of student names and score values, then find the highest and lowest score.");
    System.out.println("\nThen will return the names and max/min scores.");


    //User Prompt Enter number of students
    System.out.println("\nHow many students would you like to enter: ");
    int StudentCount = scan.nextInt();

    //Create arrays: Scores, StudentFirst, StudentLast
    int [] Scores = new int[StudentCount];
    String [] StudentFirst = new String [StudentCount];
    String [] StudentLast = new String [StudentCount];


    for (int i = 0; i < Scores.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("\nStudent " + (i+1)+":");
        System.out.println("\nEnter Student's name:");
        StudentFirst[i] = scan.next();
        StudentLast[i] = scan.next();
        System.out.println("\nEnter Student's score (0-100):");
        Scores[i] = scan.nextInt();
    }
    

    int max = StudentMax(Scores);
    int min = StudentMin(Scores);
    


    for (int i = 0; i < Scores.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("\n"+StudentFirst[i] + " " + StudentLast[i] +":      " + Scores[i]); 
    }
    
    
    for (int i = 0; i < Scores.length; i++)  {
        if (Scores [i] == max) {
            System.out.println("\n"+ StudentFirst[i] +" "+ StudentLast[i] + " has the highest score => " +max+ " and " + StudentFirst[i]+" " + StudentLast[i]+ " has the lowest => " +min);         
        }
    }
    
    
    
    //This is the sentence format that I need to make work, but I am struggling to understand how to align the index for names and scores. 
    //System.out.println("\n"+StudentFirst[i] +" "+ StudentLast[i]+ " has the highest score => " +max+ " and " +StudentFirst[i] +" "+ StudentLast [i]+ " has the lowest score => " +min);
    
    
     
    
    


    //Scan Close
    scan.close();
    //Close Program
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass back the index not the value

```
private static int StudentMin(int[] Scores) {
    int ScoreMin = Scores[0];
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < Scores.length; i++){
        if (Scores[i] < ScoreMin) {
            ScoreMin = Scores[i];
            index = i;
        }
    }
    return index;
}
```

Then you can use it later

```
int index = StudentMax(Scores);

System.out.println("\n"+ StudentFirst[index] +" "+ StudentLast[index] + " has the highest score => " +Scored[index]);
```

**Note** Please pay attention to Java naming conventions

Comment: I did try this and am running into the same issues where the name repeats for the Min index. I think this would work for a single statement, but I'm needing to have the max/min within the same sentence.

Comment: do `int maxIndex = StudentMax(Scores);` then `int minIndex = StudentMin(Scores);`

Comment: I feel a bit derp, but that worked. Thanks very much for the help and guidance. On trying to understand the theory of this, does the method push the array forward to be able to do it, or is it just reading the array for the value and pulling it out?

Comment: If you are happy with this answer, please do not forget to upvote and/or accept it.

Comment: Sure thing. Thank you very much. This is my first time on the site.